# SQL Join Question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting question for an SQL Join. I have 2 tables, examples below:

Table1: ID (int), Value(string)
Table2: ID (int), ForeignID(int), (Value)

The field ForeignID in Table2 is the foreign key of the ID in Table1. For a given entry in Table1, I have multiple entries in Table2 as follows:

```
Table1:  
ID, Value  
0, "Hello World"  
1, "Bonjour"  

Table2:  
ID, ForeignID, Value  
0, 0, "First entry"  
1, 0, "Second entry"  
2, 1, "Third entry"
```

If I do an inner join such as

```
SELECT Table1.Value, Table2. Value FROM 
Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ForeignID
```

I would get

```
Hello world, First entry  
Hello world, Second entry  
Bonjour, Third entry
```

Is there a way to only get the TOP entry in Table2 such as:

```
Hello world, First entry  
Bonjour, Third entry
```

Answer (score 5):

This works too:

```
SELECT  Table1.value
        , Table2.value
FROM    Table1 
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.foreignID
        INNER JOIN (   
          SELECT    MIN(ID) AS ID, ForeignID
          FROM      Table2
          GROUP BY  ForeignID
        ) MinID ON Table2.foreignid = MinID.foreignid
                   AND Table2.id = MinID.id
```

Comment: That's a good solution if your DBMS doesn't have windowing functions.

Comment: +1 On a well indexed table, this outperforms all other solutions currently given.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Table1.Value, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Table2.Value 
          FROM Table2 
         WHERE Table2.ForeignID = Table1.ID) 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: That simple? I feel like a fool for asking.. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait! Maybe not so simple.  I made some edits.  I don't have time to set up your table structure and test it myself, but I think you can do this with TOP and/or a subquery.  Sorry I can't be more precise.

Comment: Not a foolish question at all, and I'm not sure my answer is even close. Play with it a bit and you'll get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
t1.Value, 
(  
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.Value FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.ForeignID = t1.ID
    ORDER BY t2.ID ASC
) 
FROM Table1 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged SQL, here is the ANSI SQL query (which should work on SQL Server 2005+) :

```
WITH TT (ID, ForeignID, Value, N) AS (
    SELECT ID, ForeignID, Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ForeignID ORDER BY ID)
      FROM Table2
)
    SELECT T1.Value, T2.Value
      FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN TT T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ForeignID
       AND T2.N = 1;
```

It uses a Common Table Expression and a windowing function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation that makes sure that table2 in joined to table1 on the proper key.

```
SELECT t1.Value,  
       t2.Value
  FROM Table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
       ON t2.ForeignID = (SELECT MIN(sub.ForeignID) 
                          FROM Table2 sub WHERE sub.ForeignID = t1.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit, actually, scratch that.  Tamila's answer looks better to me.**

If you can add a boolean is_first flag to your table2 then things become a lot easier and this would do the job for you:

```
SELECT table1."value", table2."value" 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.foreign_id
WHERE table2.is_first = true
```

I don't know if Daniel's, cgatian's or Leons' answers will work for your database.  I'm on Postgres and it doesn't work for me.